# trouble creating vim macro using search history

Tags: vim

My problem is when I create a vim macro, I used some search and replace in the search and replace history. So I use the arrow key to go up in the history to find it. But the trouble is the macro only record my arrow key activity not the command I find. So when I execute the macro again, the search history is changed and the result are messed up. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: can you make some example to show why pressing up/down is a must?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can solve this problem by understanding that macros record keystrokes, not the result of commands, and act accordingly.

For example, when you use the previous search with `<C-r>/` or `//`, the actual content of the last search register is not recorded. The next time you play that macro, the last search pattern will probably be different and your whole macro will be busted if you expect otherwise. You must actually type the search pattern or perform the search as part of the recording if you want your macro to be reliable.

To get a better grasp of how recording works in Vim, you can paste the macro you just recorded (macros are saved in registers, just like the stuff you yank) and study what's there.

qq
   (do stuff)
   q
   "qp

Answer (score 1):

Remember this fact and don't use such history recall commands when you record a macro. It may be not as convenient, but you'll probably amortize the effort over the repeated macro applications, anyway.

Actually, the shrewd practitioner can use this behavior of macros as a feature. By e.g. referring to the last search pattern (e.g. `:s//...`) or recalling a partial command (e.g. `:w foo<Up>`), one can record macros that are applicable to a wide variety of situations.

Finally, you can "salvage" a macro after you realize it's broken; as its contents are stored in a register, you can just re-edit, e.g. via:

```
:let @a = <C-r><C-r>=string(@a)<CR>
```